# How to switch Huawei CDMA 2252+ to USB from CD-ROM?

Tags: devices, mobile, sms, usb-modeswitch, phone

I have Huawei CDMA 2252+ phone and I want to connect it to Linux to send SMS. In Fedora 15 (64bit) it is taken as CD-ROM. This is the output of `dmesg` after the phone is plugged in.

```
[10887.524339] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[10888.614507] scsi 3:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[10888.786098] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[10888.788583] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[10888.788904] sr 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[10899.106066] sr1: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Xpwrite, Read disk info 51 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[10899.106073] sr: Sense Key : Hardware Error [current] 
[10899.106075] sr: Add. Sense: No additional sense information
```

This is the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:1010 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd.
```

Then I tried to use `usb_modeswitch` to change the device to USB as following. (My device is not in the `usb_modewitch` supported device list.)

The output of `usb_modeswitch --verbose -H -v 0x12d1 -p 0x1010`:

```
* usb_modeswitch: handle USB devices with multiple modes
* Version 1.1.6 (C) Josua Dietze 2010
* Based on libusb0 (0.1.12 and above)

! PLEASE REPORT NEW CONFIGURATIONS !

DefaultVendor=  0x12d1
DefaultProduct= 0x1010
TargetVendor=   not set
TargetProduct=  not set
TargetClass=    not set
TargetProductList=""

DetachStorageOnly=0
HuaweiMode=1
SierraMode=0
SonyMode=0
GCTMode=0
KobilMode=0
MessageEndpoint=  not set
MessageContent=""
NeedResponse=0
ResponseEndpoint= not set
Interface=0x00

InquireDevice enabled (default)
Success check disabled
System integration mode disabled


Looking for default devices ...
searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0002
searching devices, found USB ID 1d6b:0001
searching devices, found USB ID 12d1:1010
found matching vendor ID
found matching product ID
adding device
searching devices, found USB ID 0e0f:0003
searching devices, found USB ID 0e0f:0002
Found devices in default mode, class or configuration (1)
Accessing device 005 on bus 002 ...
Getting the current device configuration ...
OK, got current device configuration (1)
Using endpoints 0x0b (out) and 0x8a (in)
Using endpoints 0x0b (out) and 0x8a (in)
Not a storage device, skipping SCSI inquiry

USB description data (for identification)
-------------------------
Manufacturer: Huawei, Incorporated
  Product: Huawei Technologies
Serial No.: not provided
-------------------------
Sending Huawei control message ...
OK, Huawei control message sent
-> Run lsusb to note any changes. Bye.
```

After this I ran the `lsusb` and I did not notice any changes. However following are notified in `dmesg`:

```
[  180.438107] usb 2-2.1: USB disconnect, address 4
[  199.385604] usb 2-2.1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 5
[  199.648757] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1010
[  199.648759] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  199.648761] usb 2-2.1: Product: Huawei Technologies
[  199.648762] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: Huawei, Incorporated
```

The following is taken from `/var/log/messages`.

```
kernel: [  180.438107] usb 2-2.1: USB disconnect, address 4
kernel: [  199.385604] usb 2-2.1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 5
kernel: [  199.648757] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1010
kernel: [  199.648759] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
kernel: [  199.648761] usb 2-2.1: Product: Huawei Technologies
kernel: [  199.648762] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: Huawei, Incorporated
mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1"
mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
```

I'm not sure whether I have successfully switched the phone from CD-ROM to USB. Is there any way to confirm this? I don't have any `ttyUSB` file under `/dev` folder. How to find which file corresponds to the above device? Further, I want to send AT commands to the phone. How to do that?